# Proving `T b` when `b` is already matched on

Tags: boolean, agda, inspect

I am trying to prove something simple:

```
open import Data.List
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Bool
open import Data.Bool.Properties
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Unit

repeat : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} → ℕ → A → List A
repeat zero x = []
repeat (suc n) x = x ∷ repeat n x

filter-repeat : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} → (p : A → Bool) → (x : A) → T (p x) → ∀ n →
  filter p (repeat n x) ≡ repeat n x
```

I thought proving `filter-repeat` is going to be easy by pattern matching on `p x`:

```
filter-repeat p x prf zero = refl
filter-repeat p x prf (suc n) with p x
filter-repeat p x () (suc n) | false
filter-repeat p x prf (suc n) | true  = cong (_∷_ x) (filter-repeat p x prf n)
```

However this complains that `prf : ⊤` is not of type `T (p x)`. So I thought, OK, this seems like a familiar problem, let's whip out `inspect`:

```
filter-repeat p x prf zero = refl
filter-repeat p x prf (suc n) with p x | inspect p x
filter-repeat p x () (suc n) | false | _
filter-repeat p x tt (suc n) | true  | [ eq ] rewrite eq = cong (_∷_ x) (filter-repeat p x {!!} n)
```

but despite the `rewrite`, the type of the hole is still `T (p x)` instead of `T true`. Why is that? How do I reduce its type to `T true` so I can fill it with `tt`?

**Workaround**

I was able to work around it by using `T-≡`:

```
open import Function.Equality using (_⟨$⟩_)
open import Function.Equivalence

filter-repeat : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} → (p : A → Bool) → (x : A) → T (p x) → ∀ n →
  filter p (repeat n x) ≡ repeat n x
filter-repeat p x prf zero = refl
filter-repeat p x prf (suc n) with p x | inspect p x
filter-repeat p x () (suc n) | false | _
filter-repeat p x tt (suc n) | true  | [ eq ] = cong (_∷_ x) (filter-repeat p x (Equivalence.from T-≡ ⟨$⟩ eq) n)
```

but I would still like to understand why the `inspect`-based solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As **András Kovács** says the inductive case requires `prf` to be of type `T (p x)` while you've already changed it to just `⊤` by pattern matching on `p x`. One simple solution is just to call `filter-repeat` recursively before pattern matching on `p x`:

```
open import Data.Empty

filter-repeat : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} → (p : A → Bool) → (x : A) → T (p x) → ∀ n →
  filter p (repeat n x) ≡ repeat n x
filter-repeat p x prf  0      = refl
filter-repeat p x prf (suc n) with filter-repeat p x prf n | p x
... | r | true  = cong (x ∷_) r
... | r | false = ⊥-elim prf
```

It also can sometimes be useful to use [the protect pattern](https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2016/008447.html):

```
data Protect {a} {A : Set a} : A → Set where
  protect : ∀ x → Protect x

filter-repeat : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} → (p : A → Bool) → (x : A) → T (p x) → ∀ n →
  filter p (repeat n x) ≡ repeat n x
filter-repeat p x q  0      = refl
filter-repeat p x q (suc n) with protect q | p x | inspect p x
... | _ | true  | [ _ ] = cong (x ∷_) (filter-repeat p x q n)
... | _ | false | [ r ] = ⊥-elim (subst T r q)
```

`protect q` saves the type of `q` from being rewritten, but it also means that in the `false` case the type of `q` is still `T (p x)` rather than `⊥`, hence the additional `inspect`.

Another variant of the same idea is

```
module _ {a} {A : Set a} (p : A → Bool) (x : A) (prf : T (p x)) where
  filter-repeat : ∀ n → filter p (repeat n x) ≡ repeat n x
  filter-repeat  0      = refl
  filter-repeat (suc n) with p x | inspect p x
  ... | true  | [ r ] = cong (x ∷_) (filter-repeat n)
  ... | false | [ r ] = ⊥-elim (subst T r prf)
```

`module _ ... (prf : T (p x)) where` prevents the type of `prf` from being rewritten as well.

Answer (score 3):

Dependent pattern matching only affects the goal and the context at the exact point of their use. Matching on `p x`rewrites the current context and reduces the type of `prf` to `⊤` in the `true` branch.

However, when you do the recursive `filter-repeat` call, you once again supply `x` as argument there, and `T (p x)` in `filter-repeat` depends on *that* `x`, not the old one in the outer context, even though they're definitionally equal. We could've passed something other than `x`, hypothetically, so no assumption can be made about it before the `filter-repeat` call.

`x` can be made invariant in the context by factoring it out from the induction:

```
open import Data.Empty

filter-repeat : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} → (p : A → Bool) → (x : A) → T (p x) → ∀ n →
  filter p (repeat n x) ≡ repeat n x
filter-repeat p x prf = go where
  go : ∀ n → filter p (repeat n x) ≡ repeat n x
  go zero    = refl
  go (suc n) with p x | inspect p x
  go (suc n) | true  | [ eq ] = cong (_∷_ x) (go n)
  go (suc n) | false | [ eq ] = ⊥-elim (subst T eq prf)
```